# Sliding with jquery - one element is above second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three html "slides" (like in presentation) and switcher, which toggle them.

**Good model situation:**

1. First slide is visible
2. Switch to second slide
3. First slide slides to left edge out of the page
4. New slide (seconds) slides from right to the page immediately after first slide (let's say, that edges of slides are touching)

**What I get with my code**

1. First slide is visible
2. Switch to second slide
3. First slide slides to left edge out of the page
4. New slide (seconds) slides from right, but underneath the first slide. Left bottom corner of the first slide is touching right top corner of the second slide.

I think it's probably CSS issue, but I don't have any idea how to fix it. I don't want to forget important parts of code, [so here is live preview](http://umimseprosadit.lukasholeczy.eu/). The part about I'm talking is at the end of page.

Comment: I tried putting the sections inside a div with overflow: hidden and height: 1100px. It does not show the image running below, but the animation is still wrong, the second slide stil jumps up. For what I understood, the slide function wraps the section inside a div, right? Is it a library function or you coded it?

Comment: @karel-poláček - I've updated my answer to make it more clear...you misinterpreted step 1. Wrap all slides in one `.myCarousel` div. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Really nice answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Wrap the `section` divs in another container, with a class of say, `.myCarousel`.

```
<div class="myCarousel">

  <section> 
    <!-- Slide 1 Content -->
  </section>
 <section> 
    <!-- Slide 2 Content -->
  </section>
  <section> 
    <!-- Slide 3 Content -->
  </section>

</div> <!-- End of .myCarousel-->
```

2) Give `.myCarousel` the following CSS:

```
.myCarousel{
  position:relative;
  min-height:1100px;
}
```

(The min-height was taken from your markup. if the height of the slides differ, use JavaScript to dynamically set this height when the carousel pager is clicked).

3) Your slides are contained within `<section>` tags, so add the following to the `section` CSS style:

```
section{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

The issue was regarding the CSS and the non-typical way the slideshow is created. It looks like you're using jQuery UI slide effect to transition between slides (I've seen the jQuery `animate` effect used more). This is fine, but we need to add some structure to the carousel and some styles to make sure the slides are where they should be.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tryied it, but now all slides are loaded and only one is visible. For better understanding it's on [live preview](http://umimseprosadit.lukasholeczy.eu/).